# How to get path of external storage android?

Tags: android

I would like to get external root path. I got it like that:

```
root = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath)
```

but after release android 10 it has become deprecated. I know that you will say that here I could find a lot of solutions but I didn't manage to solve my problem :( The most popular solution is that:

```
ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDir(String)
```

but this solution didn't help me. I also saw these questions: [question_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027531/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecation-alternatives),[question_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501355/getexternalstoragedirectory-not-working) and [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external-select-location). The one solution which I see is to write smth like that: `/storage/emulated/0/` and maybe it will do what I want. But maybe you have better solution for this task?

Comment: try this. `String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Dirname";
        File dir = new File(path);`

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated as you know :(

Comment: have you check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116335/environment-getexternalstoragedirectory-deprecated-in-api-level-29-java

Comment: @mapy, and as I see it returns smth like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.my/files` but I need another path as you can at my question

Comment: "I would like to get external root path" -- why? The value is useless to you on Android 10+, as you cannot use it for reading or writing files.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so this `/storage/emulated/0/` path is useless?

Comment: You cannot read or write to that location, so I do not know what you would use it for.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I use this location for moving for ex to downloads directory or to smth else :)

Comment: Well, [you cannot do that anymore using the filesystem](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html). Your choices are using the Storage Access Framework or possibly `MediaStore`. See [this blog post series](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html) for more on those two approaches.